row average of triangular array of binary random variables
Suppose that I have a triangular array of binary random variables, elements in each row are possibly dependent on others, but marginals are the same.
$T_1 = \{X_{11}\}$ where $X_i \sim Bern(p_1) $
$T_2 = \{X_{21}, X_{22}\}$ where $X_i \sim Bern(p_2)$
$T_3 = \{X_{31}, X_{32}, X_{33}\}$ where $X_i \sim Bern(p_3)$
and so on. Here $p_i$ decays to zero fast enough, say exponentially fast.
For this, I want to say that $P[\frac{1}{i} \sum_{j=1}^i X_{ij} < \epsilon] \to 1$ as $i \to \infty$.
My attempt: Intuitively, this looks super simple. So I first tried some concentration inequality, but it failed because each row is a dependent sequence. I also tried Borel-Cantelli lemma, but I don't know how to properly define "infinitely often" for each row because each row is a finite sequence.

This is doable; use Markov’s inequality. $P(A_n>\epsilon)\le p_n/\epsilon$, where $A_n$ is the average of the nth row.
